# Trying to get this linked list started

Tags: java

Second programming class
So we have been tasked with a linked list, building each method from scratch.
Well I started on this day before yesterday and had a null pointer exception, I figured id iron it out later and continued.
Well after cutting my program down to nothing to find the culprit im left with code that SHOULD work as its copied from our lab (that worked).
If you guys think you can figure out why im getting a null pointer exception on my add method id greatly appreciate it and see if im doing the second constructor correctly. If I can get SOME traction on this to get started it would go allot easier but as is I cant even begin.

You will notice allot of blank methods, ill get to them once I can get my constructor + add method working

My code:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Created by hhhh on 11/2/2014.
 */
public class Lset<R> implements Set151Interface<R> {

    private Node    head;
    private int     length;

    /**In the first (following) constructor im trying to re use code and call my clear method.
     *Should save space and make code look cleaner.
     */
    public Lset(){
        clear();
    }

    public Lset(Collection<? extends R> list){
        this();
        for (R object : list) {
            add(object);
        }


    }

    /**
     * Copied from Lab7, this add method checks to see if there are more nodes than just the head.
     * After the check if false, creates a new node and adds it to the end of the list.
     * @param entry
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean add(R entry) {
        Node newNode = new Node(entry);

        // empty list is handled differently from a non-empty list
        if (head.next == null) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            Node lastNode = getNodeAt(length - 1);
            lastNode.next = newNode;
        }
        length++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        this.length     = 0;
        this.head       = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<R> iterator() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends R> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] array) {
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Code used in Lab 7, getNodeAt uses the length field and starts at head to traverse array and arrive at the
     * position desired.
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    private Node getNodeAt(int position) {
        assert !isEmpty() && (position >= 0) && position < length;

        Node cNode = head;

        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++)
            cNode = cNode.next;

        assert cNode != null;
        return cNode;
    }


    public String toString(){
        String arrayString = "<";
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            String two = getNodeAt(i).toString();
            arrayString += two;
            if(i <= (length - 2)){
                two = ", ";
                arrayString += two;
            }

        }
        arrayString += ">";

        return arrayString;
    }

    //TODO comment better
    public class Node {
        /** Reference to the data */
        public R data;
        /** Reference to the next node is in the list */
        public Node next;

        /**
         * Sets the data for this node.
         * @param data data to be carried by this node.
         */
        public Node(R data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the data for the node and assigns the next node in the list.
         * @param data data to be carried by this node.
         * @param nextNode next node in the list.
         */
        public Node(R data, Node nextNode) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = nextNode;
        }
        /**
         * Returns just the data portion of the node.
         * @return The data portion of the node.
         */
        public R getData() {
            return this.data;
        }
        /**
         * Modified just the data portion of the node.
         * @param data new data to be contained within the node.
         */
        public void setData(R data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        /**
         * What node does this node point to.
         * @return the node that this node points to or null if it does not
         * point anywhere.
         */
        public Node getNextNode() {
            return this.next;
        }

        /**
         * Change the node that this node points to.
         * @param nextNode a new node for this node to point to.
         */
        public void setNextNode(Node nextNode) {
            this.next = nextNode;
        }

        /**
         * Display the state of just the data portion of the node.
         */
        public String toString() {
            return this.data.toString();
        }
    }



}
```

This is the method in main thats killing it

```
private void testConstruction() {
        System.out.println("\nTesting Constructor");
        System.out.print("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        Set151Interface s = makeSet();
        //added
        s.add("Butterfinger");
        test(s.size() == 0,

                "size() should return 0: " + s.size());
        test(s.toString().equals("<>"),
                "toString returns \"<>\": " + s.toString());


        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        temp.add("Butterfinger");
        temp.add("Milky Way");
        temp.add("Kit Kat");
        temp.add("Three Muskateers");

        Set151Interface s3 = makeSet(temp);
            test(s3.size() == 4,
                "size should return 4: " + s3.size());
        test(s3.toString().equals("<Butterfinger, Milky Way, Kit Kat, Three Muskateers>"),
                "toString should return\n        "+
                        "\"<Butterfinger, Milky Way, Kit Kat, Three Muskateers>\":\n       "
                        + s3.toString());

    }
```

as soon as butterfinger attempts to get added I get null pointer exception pointing to this line
`if (head.next == null) {`

Comment: When trying to build a complete library, unit testint (Junit or TestNG) is your friend ...

Answer (score 1):

You just declared `private Node    head;` and it doesnt takes any value assigned . so the compiler throws `NPE`

Comment: Compilers don't throw exceptions (unless the compiler itself has a bug).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, I figured it out :).
On day one I had edited my driver (and forgot) once I re copied the driver everything works (so far) thanks again guys!